# Finding out who added me to a large group chat on Skype

Tags: skype

Is there a way to find out who added me to a large group chat on Skype? I keep getting added to a large conversation with around 45 people and I can't figure out who it is as I have added many people throughout my years of playing video games and have no idea who it could be.

Is there any way to identify who is adding me so that I can remove them from my friend list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The group that you get added should have the name of the person who added it

We use Skype group chat and whoever adds somebody to a group that message is broadcasted in the group

So look in the main group history as to when u were added there should be a broadcast message about who added you